# Prolog: Chaining multiple rules

Tags: prolog

So I am an absolute beginner in Prolog. I am learning recursion at the moment and this is what I got until now on my task.

```
dance(start). 
dance(forward(T)) :- dance(T). 
dance(backward(T)) :- dance(T). 

count(start,0,0).                   
count(forward(X),succ(Y),Z) :- count(X,Y,Z).  
count(backward(X),Y,succ(Z)) :- count(X,Y,Z).   

greater(succ(0),0).   
greater(succ(Y),succ(Z)):-greater(Y,Z).`
```

Summary of what this is supposed to do: There can be dances starting with the "start" and then either forward or backward addition per recursion. In count, I managed to be able to count the amount of forward and backward in a given sequence and save them in the "succ" notation and in greater I want to compare two of such "succ" numbers. And greater shall be true if the first argument is larger (consists of more "succs" than the second argument.

Now my task is to write a new rule "more(X)" which is true if the sequence X (build from dance) has more forward than backward in it. I think I have all the subtasks I need for it but now I am helpless with chaining them together because until now I only had  2 rules with the same amount of parameters but in this case, I got one with one, two, and three parameters. The solution should be something like this

`more(X):-greater(Y,Z)`

but how do I get my "succ" umbers from "count" to "greater" and the given sequence X to "count"? I do have to change some of the rules otherwise count is never called, right?

So it should be more like `more(X):-greater(count(X,Y,Z))` ?

But like this, I would have to change the greater rules to be able to "get" this type of parameter.

Example query ?- more(backward(forward(start))).

false.

?- more(forward(start)).

true.

Comment: Your `count` doesn't seem to work; have you pasted the wrong version here? As you have it there, It needs a version of `greater` which takes three parameters, and there isn't one in your code. `count` should refer to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `dance/1` and `count/3` predicates seems correct.

If you want "greater" where `greater(X, Y)` means that X is greater than Y, you'd write:

```
greater(succ(_), 0).
greater(succ(X), succ(Y)) :- greater(X, Y).
```

Your solution checks if X is *exactly one* greater than Y.

Note that nothing is greater than 0.

If you implement `more/1` in terms of `count/3` and `greater/2`, you'd write:

```
more(X) :-
    count(X, Forward, Backward),
    greater(Forward, Backward).
```

Comment: Thank you. If I understand that more rule correct it first checks for possible  solutions for instantiating Foward and Backward since they are variables here and it is only true if Forward and Backward are these "succ" numbers as they were calculated by my "count". So there is only one pair for "Forward and Backward" so that count is true for a given X. Afterwards Prolog tries make a Unification with count and greater to see if these Forwards and Backwards variables also fullfill greater.

Comment: @krs I guess this is roughly correct. Don't overdo it with the verbal explanations, the code is much more obvious than any "natural language" description of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> So it should be more like `more(X):-greater(count(X,Y,Z))` ?

No, you are writing that as if it is Python and `greater(count(X,Y,Z))` will call `greater(...)` on the return from count. Prolog predicates are not function calls, and `count(...)` does not return anything in that way.

The result of the count is Y and Z. (These names you are using could be clearer). Do the count, and then after, use the Y and Z for something else.

```
count(X,Y,Z),
greater(Y,Z)
```

The comma being AND; "this code works if count of X is Y and Z AND Y is greater than Z".